# Failed to get the task for process 1640. Error when trying to run iPhone app on device

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am getting the following error whenever I try to install my Cocos2d game on an iPhone device.

Failed to get the task for process 1640

I am using xCode 4.0.2 which I really hate as it is simply too complicated. I have set the build settings for my target but when I click on the project it says no build settings have been configured as shown in the screenshot below: 
[image]

Although the app fails to run on the device but when I use my iPhone and click on the app it does run without using xCode.

Comment: Azam, did you start this project new under Xcode4, or is it from an older version? I see deployment target is 3.2, which can be an issue. I think Xcode4 only supports iOS 4 and up.

Comment: @nash No, you can support all the way back to 3.0.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure you are using a debug configuration and not a release or ad hoc configuration to deploy to the device.

Go to the Build select box at the upper left of the Xcode main window. Select the "Scheme" that isn't building and select Edit Scheme.

In the next dialog select Run on the left hand side and Info on the right. Make sure Build Configuration is set to Debug.

Comment: I did this, but it is still not working. Env: phonegap,xcode4
and i applied some provisioning changes few days ago.