# Failed to get the task for process 3695

Tags: iphone, xcode

I get this message when trying to launch my app on my friends device:

"Failed to get the task for process 3695"

Anyone knows what it means? Google didn't help me much...

Comment: Did You add your friend's device id in your  development provisioning file

Comment: of course… i tried without and it told me i don't have the right provision for it.

Comment: what is OS of your xcode and your friend's device?

Comment: My Xcode is 4.5 and his OS is 5.1.1

Comment: check out these link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734130/failed-to-get-the-task-for-process-1640-error-when-trying-to-run-iphone-app-on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488600/iphone-debugging-how-to-resolve-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959645/error-launching-remote-program-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process-699

Answer (score 2):

Solved it, i guess it was because i tried running it with Distribution profile instead of Development.

Thank you all!