# debugging iphone app on device giving error

Tags: iphone, debugging

While trying to debug app on device, error "failed to get the task for process 12567" comes. This is happening with my app only when try to run any other app on same device and system, it functions well. What could be wrong no idea. In my app i am using zbar sdk and tapku library framework. Please guide and if any other info required feel free to ask.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Adhoc or distribution profile doesn't support debugging. You need to debug with a Development

profile, and use the Adhoc or distribution profile only for distributing. I think you debug with adhoc

or distribution profile. `Just check it.`

Comment: Also check on device that another app with same bundle identifier name don't run...

Comment: Means check that on your device two apps which have same bundle id name not exist...

Comment: Also check these discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734130/failed-to-get-the-task-for-process-1640-error-when-trying-to-run-iphone-app-on & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488600/iphone-debugging-how-to-resolve-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process